# UDF that fetches array data is not getting up to date data when the array is changed from Worksheet Change Event

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have a variable number of cells (~500 to 10,000+) whose values need to be retrieved as they are changed. I have a WorkSheet_Change event that captures changes to these cells and makes updates to an array.  Further calculation and updates occur within the array structure to come up the result(s).

I had originally done this with multiple hidden sheets, but the performance was terrible.  With the memory based arrays, everything works fast and fine up to this point.

I have a bunch of cells that represents the sum of parts of the dependent range(s) that could change. If the value within these cells changes, I know the dependent cells have changed and the latest calculations should be ready to fetched from the array.

The problem is that the function is fetching data from the array before the Change event has updated the array, and hence you see the 'previous' value.

A simplified simulation of the problem:

In a Module:

```
Option Explicit

Public tData(1 To 1, 1 To 1) As Double

Public Function GetArrayData(CelltoCheckForChanges) As Double
    If IsEmpty(tData) Then tData(1, 1) = 0
    GetArrayData = tData(1, 1)
End Function
```

In the Worksheet code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If (Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("D3")) Is Nothing) Then
        tData(1, 1) = Target.Value
    End If
    
End Sub
```

In the sheet, set cell B3 to be "=GetArrayData(D3)"  and then enter numbers in to cell D3.  The numbers in B3 will reflect the 'previous' value.  FYI, the "CelltoCheckForChanges" in the GetArrayData is the reference to cell that flags if there has been a change in any of the dependent cells to trigger a fetch from the array (the dependent cells are not shown for simplicity).

I have tried placing disabling/enabling events as well as manual vs auto calcs around the change event with no impact.  (FYI, trying to avoid switching calc on/off if it all possible).

Hope someone can provide some insight, fixes or ideas for alternative approaches on this.

Comment: I don't understand the need for Worksheet_Change event. Why can't the function contents be `tData(1, 1) = IIf(IsEmpty(tData(1, 1)), 0, pIgnoreThis): GetArrayData = tData(1, 1)`  and no change event?

Comment: thank you Qharr for your input - i have added some extra context in the question, because i may have over simplified the example.   the value of "D3" is not what needs to be loaded, it is the potentially hundreds of dependent cells that sum to D3.  With your suggestion, i would need to find the cells that changed to work out what to load.

Comment: Excel does Calculation before worksheet_change, so you need to force the UDF to calculate again after the Change event. Maybe the worksheet change event could toggle the value of a trigger cell that is passed as to an additional UDF parameter.

Comment: thank you Charles, love your profiler btw which I am using to optimize this app!. Have just tried this and it is working but the UDF is running twice which is not ideal.  I am not familiar with building DLLs but wondering if I externalized as VSTO/DLL module whether this would (a) allow this limitation to be changed, and (b) run faster.